# How to write code for current date + 1 hour in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a requirement to Add 1 hour to the current date. I can able to get current date by using below funcation. I am new to xslt code, can able to add an hour to current date.

<xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>

please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-add-dayTimeDuration-to-dateTime, it defines the `+` operator for `xs:dateTime` and `xs:dayTimeDuration` so `current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1H')` gives the wanted result.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I can able to get the 1 hour added time.